# Saving JSON data to database at a certain time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to truncate and save JSON data from an external URL at a certain time (10pm) every day. The URL requires a login which I have access to, but not sure how best to implement this.

The JSON is structured as such:

```
{
  "Region": [{"id":"1","region":"South"}],
  "Agent": [{"id":"1","first_name":"Tim","last_name":"Jones"}]
}
```

I have created the model's `Region` and `Agent` to store the data in, matching the fields above.

This is what I have so far in `Region` model

```
json = JSON.parse('http://....')

json['Region'].each do |data|
  Region.create(
    id: data['id'],
    region: data['region']
  )
```

My questions are:

- Is this possible via the model, or do I have to place this in a
  controller
- How do I go about truncating and saving at a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the data from an external url, you'll need to use an http client such as Faraday or Httparty
2. Once you got your json data you can parse and manipulate it however you want.
3. To automate it at 10pm every day you need to schedule a background job using something like ActiveJob or Sidekiq.

Comment: Thanks for the information @EJ2015. Is it best practice to use the model to do this? What I have above just doesn't seem to save when I replace the URL with JSON data.

Comment: Normally what you described would be implemented in a model, or a worker class (e.g. with Sidekiq). If you fail to save the data in db, check the errors (make sure you're saving the right data type and they're valid).